Помогите достать элемент из JSON
Помогите мне написать код.
Я когда-то написала это:
import openai

openai.api_key = ‘--------------------------’
responce_text = openai.Completion.create(
    model=‘text-davinci-003’,
    prompt=‘How old am I?’,
    max_tokens=1000,
    n=1
)
for index, text in enumerate(responce_text[‘choices’]):
    print(f’Possible answer{index}')
    print(text[‘text’])

В итоге на печать выводились лишь порядковый номер и текст строки...
Мне нужно сделать то же самое с этим:
from roboflow import Roboflow

rf = Roboflow(api_key=“---------------------------”)
project = rf.workspace().project(“project-daemx”)
model = project.version(“1”).model
file = “screenshot.jpg”

# Измените эту строку так, чтобы печаталось только имя «класса», а не все целиком.

print(model.predict(file, confidence=40, overlap=30).json())

Измените эту строку так, чтобы печаталось только имя «класса», а не все целиком.
Сейчас печатается:
{'predictions': [{'x': 421, 'y': 43, 'width': 54, 'height': 36, 'confidence': 0.9455991387367249, **'class': '20'**, 'class_id': 14, 'detection_id': 'a8caf054-b05a-41c0-bed2-af83cf655cf8', 'image_path': 'screenshot.jpg', 'prediction_type': 'ObjectDetectionModel'}}], 'image': {'width': '830', 'height': '485'}}

Должно:
'class': '20'
Прошу прощения, если что-то нарушила!

Вам нужно получить значение 'predictions', затем в массиве получить значение объекта 'class'. В чём заключается проблема?

Я что-то не соображу как? 'predictions' - это где?

Это ключ в вашем JSON объекте

Я не знаю что такое JSON... Вы код не напишите?

Машинное обучение тут вообще не при чём, вопрос про работу с JSON, который сводится к словарям и спискам.

Получить значение class можно следующим образом:
print(model.predict(file, confidence=40, overlap=30).json()['predictions'][0]['class'])


На выходе получаем 6

Пишет: IndexError: list index out of range

Отправьте, пожалуйста, сюда то что вы получаете  в результате этой операции print(model.predict(file, confidence=40, overlap=30).json())

Я получаю: {'predictions': [{'x': 421, 'y': 43, 'width': 54, 'height': 36, 'confidence': 0.9455991387367249, 'class': '20', 'class_id': 14, 'detection_id': 'a8caf054-b05a-41c0-bed2-af83cf655cf8', 'image_path': 'screenshot.jpg', 'prediction_type': 'ObjectDetectionModel'}}], 'image': {'width': '830', 'height': '485'}}

У вас почему-то объект содержит ошибку в виде лишней скобки до закрытия массива.

{'predictions': [{'x': 421, 'y': 43, 'width': 41, 'height': 37, 'confidence': 0.9766784906387329, 'class': '6', 'class_id': 27, 'detection_id': 'acb816b9-31dc-4844-8704-cd880dbd312c', 'image_path': 'screenshot.jpg', 'prediction_type': 'ObjectDetectionModel'}], 'image': {'width': '830', 'height': '485'}}

Теперь также воспользуйтесь моим ответом и скажите, что получается.

IndexError: list index out of range

Из тех данных, что вы мне отправили, всё исправно работает. Сложно предположить, что у вас там происходит. Ясно только то, что элемент массива, к которому вы обращаетесь, не существует.

Посмотрите скриншот, который я приложил в ответе, я работаю с теми данными, которые вы мне отправили.

А циклом можно?

Не понимаю с какой целью. Я в ответе просто написал, как обратиться к определённому элементу, в вашем случае class. Скорее всего вы оперируете другими данными, от того и получается ошибка.

Ben Puls, спасибо вам огромное! Я разобралась! Спасибо вам за то, что не бросили девушку одну)
